# Reactivate Windows Server 2008 R2 without internet connection

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, license

I have an application running on **Windows Server 2008 R2**.

The thing is we just have to format the OS, and work with an evaluation version of windows downloaded from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11093

Altought it says **180 days trial evaluation**, as the server cannot connect to internet, it only gave us **10 days**.

Now the 10 days are about to expire we need to activate it but without internet connection.

After some research, we found this command: `SLMGR.vbs /rearm` to reactivate the 10 day trial period, but we don't know if it works without internet connection.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
There's another option, we can connect to internet through proxy so maybe we can use the command SLMGR.vbs through a proxy. But im not finding any documentation or how to.

Comment: Set up internet from a cell phone and share the cell phone connection. You need some sort of Internet as the Server OS is out of support and I am fairly sure Microsoft Sales Support will not help with a trial.

Comment: You could activate Windows Server 2008R2 through the phone.  Have you tried that?  I didn't think it was actually possible to convert an elevation into an activated installation using a real license key. Why didn't you use your original Windows Server 2008R2 ISO from the Volume Licensing Service Center website?  **You won't be able to extend the trial, that does require an internet connection, you can only activate VLK installations over the phone.**  I actually did that recently.

Comment: Phone is not an option as the 10 days expire tomorrow (sunday). Also, the server CANNOT connect to internet in any ways (phone, network, and so on)

Comment: "server CANNOT connect to internet in any ways (phone"  <-- something wrong with the Server Network?

Comment: No, it's filtered by several firewalls, it has a network but it's an internal server for an app used in a client. And also, it doesnt have a wifi network card.

Comment: Seems like the client just cut himself off from the Microsoft activation servers. The practical solution might be to take the server out from that strong-room to activate Windows.

Comment: And what if we have a proxy? how do i activate it through proxy? ill update the question

Comment: If the server can't access the internet, it won't also be able to connect to a proxy server on the internet. Note that even after the activation period has elapsed you may still do the activation, but you need the internet.

Comment: I have a proxy accesible through LAN and that proxy has Internet.